# Range() in python 2.7 v. 3

Tags: python, range

Just wondering how to get the same functionality out of range() that you get in python 2.7 in version 3?

In python 2.7:

```
>>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In python 3:

```
>>> range(5)
range(0, 5)
```

I need to get a list that looks like the one above, but am restricted to using python3 for an assignment...

Thanks so much!

Comment: It still kind of behaves like a list, so aside from the way it shows up in the REPL, is it causing any problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
list(range(5))
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In Python 3, [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#range) returns an iterable of objects, but it's easy to convert it to a list, as shown above.